# HTTP Python - Image not loading

Tags: python, html, image, http

Evening guys!

I tryed some googling about this issue but i didn't find nothing really good to help me, so i game here. The thing is: I want to load a image to my HTTP server but it just doesn't work as intended. My code is:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open(r"calculator.png")

class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        # processamento
        if self.path in ("/", "Aula12_HTML.html", "/Aula12_2_HTML.html", im):
            # linha de resposta
            self.send_response(200, "OK")

            # linhas de cabeçalhos
            self.send_header("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")

            # linha em branco
            self.end_headers()

            if self.path == "/":
                self.path = "/Aula12_HTML.html"

            f = open(self.path[1:])

            # Resposta do Servidor
            self.wfile.write(f.read().encode())
        else:
            self.send_response(404, "NOT FOUND")
```

And one of my HTML codes is this simple one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title> Bossbattle </title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <h1> A Calculadora </h1>
    <img src="calculator.png" alt= ">:C" title="U SHAL PERISH"/>
    <p> Olá, seja bem-vi... <b> Você não é bem vindo nessa página!! >:C </b> </p>
    <form action="calcular" method="POST">
        Nível da habílidade      [numb]: <input type="text" name="n1" value="" /> <br>
        Força da habilidade      [numb]: <input type="text" name="n2" value="" /> <br>
        Resisten a habilidade [+-*/]: <input type="text" name="n3" value="" /> <br>
        <input type="submit" name="Enviar" value="Atacar" />
    </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `im` is a PIL Image object.  It's not a URL string.  You need to add the URL you'll be looking for.  Further, if you do get a request for the image, you'll need to set the `Content-Type` to `image/png`, not `text/html`, and you don't want to encode it.  You'll need to read it as a binary.  You don't really need PIL in here at all.

Comment: You helped my a lot with this tip mate, i would name this an answer! In 3 minutes the code is working. Thanks o/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a version that works:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        # processamento
        if self.path in ("/", "/Aula12_2_HTML.html"):
            print("html")
            self.send_response(200, "OK")
            self.send_header("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
            self.end_headers()

            document = "Aula12_HTML.html"

            f = open(document)

            self.wfile.write(f.read().encode())
        elif self.path == '/calculator.png':
            self.send_response(200, "OK")
            self.send_header("Content-Type", "image/png")
            self.end_headers()

            self.wfile.write(open('calculator.png','rb').read())
        else:
            self.send_response(404, "NOT FOUND")

httpd = HTTPServer(('127.0.0.1', 8080), RequestHandler )
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Roberts, I really want to thank you! You saved me with both of your answers (I would like to add a up vote but since I don't have reputation I can't do that yet) .

Comment: Great!  The `http.server` module is nifty for little experiments, but if your site gets any more complicated, you're going to want to investigate one of the Python web frameworks: Django, Flask, CherryPy, etc.  They help automate almost all of the tedious stuff.